# Button click execute 2 times on modal jquery

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, click, materialize

I don't understand why the button click event it's firing 2 times....I'm drawing 2 cards on materialize css ...and when I press the button it checks if the client session is start, and do something...else it opens a modal. But the click must fire only 1 time, I'm getting 2 times alert("chango"), on 1 click...HELP PLS!!, here is the code:

```
function list_section(data) {
    var p = JSON.parse(data); // 2 results
    $.each(p, function(i, item) {
    if (item.SECTION_ID == 1) {
        $("#president").append(
            '<div class="col s6">' +
            '\<div class="card medium sticky-action" id="president_'+item.POLITIC_ID+'">' +
            '<div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">' +
            '<div class="video-container">' +
            '  <iframe src="' + baseurl + 'public/uploads/' + item.POLITIC_FILE + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen controls></iframe>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="card-action">' +
            '<span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">' + item.POLITIC_NAME + '&nbsp' + item.POLITIC_LASTNAME + '<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>' +
            '<div class="row" style="margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:0px;">' +
            '<div class="col s3">' +
            '<button class=" btn waves-effect modal-trigger waves-light red darken-3 disapprove disapprove_president"  data-target="verification" type="submit" name="action"  ">Desapruebo</button>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="col s3 offset-s4">' +
            '<button class=" btn waves-effect modal-trigger waves-light light-green darken-3 aprove aprove_president" data-target="verification" type="submit" name="action" ">Apruebo</button>' +
             '</div>' +
             '</div>' +
             '</div>' +
             '<div class="card-reveal">' +
             '<span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">' + item.POLITIC_NAME + '&nbsp' + item.POLITIC_LASTNAME + '<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>' +
             '<p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>' +
             '</div>' +
             '</div>' +
             '<input type="hidden" id="' + item.POLITIC_ID + '">' +
             '</div>'
        );
        $(document).on('click', '.aprove , .disapprove', function() {
            // $(".aprove , .disapprove").unbind("click");
            //  $(".aprove , .disapprove").on("click", selectKeepFirstOfAll);
            if (sesion != "") {
                if ($(this).attr('class').split(' ').pop() == 'aprove_president') {
                    alert("chango");
                    var data = {}
                    $.ajax({
                        url: baseurl+'result/aprove',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: data
                    })
                    .done(function() {
                        console.log("success");
                    })
                    .fail(function() {
                        console.log("error");
                    })
                    .always(function() {
                        console.log("complete");
                    });
                }
                else if ($(this).attr('class').split(' ').pop() == 'disapprove_president') {
                }
            }
            else {
                $('#verification').openModal();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `$(document).on('click'...)` outside the `list_section` function (make it global).  You're adding an onclick handler for every section you process.

Comment: Ok , but I need the item.POLITIC_ID ...for the ajax request =(

Comment: You already have it.  You could do something like this: `$(this).closest("div.col.s6").find('input[type=hidden]').last().attr('id')` (Add a "politic_id" class to the input to make the selector more simple)

Comment: @Ragnar referring to the data when you add the click handler is a bad idea anyway, it will keep that reference and send the one set of data no matter what button you press.   Currently it will call all the handlers everytime you press any button - but even if you fix that you can't hard code the data into the handler.  You're going to have to either store your data somewhere in JavaScript or read it from your HTML